# Changing the text of the paragraph generated by Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have a Web Application in C# that's generating PDFs from rdlc files in ReportViewer. When user click on the print button in the ReportViewer, the generated PDF will be downloaded. Thats working properly.

But sometimes user needs to generate PDF with more than 100 pages and that might take some more time. And when they click Print button there is a popup that comes that say "Your PDF is ready".

Looking at the inspect this is the paragraph generated:

```
<p class="msrs-printdialog-bodytext">Your PDF is ready.</p>
```

I want to change the text to say something like "Your PDF will be downloaded shortly", because I don't want people to get confused.

I was trying something with JQuery and Javascript but I didn't have any success. Anyone that can help I will greatly appreciate it.

I was trying to fix this with JQuery and Javascript code that I found on this site but I did not have any success.